# How to read and extract values from single quotes ('') in a text file and find that value in another file, if not exits thrown an error

Tags: batch-file, text-files

new to batch file scripting. Need your all help to extract all the values which are in (single quotes) '' from below text file (file.txt) and find that value in another text file, if not exists throw an error.

```
file.txt
Wed 11/01/2023 - 19:59:23.33 
BIP1138I: Applying overrides using runtime mqsiapplybaroverrides...
BIP1140I: Overriding property FTP_To_Trg#FtpServer with 'ftp.test.com' in 'App_Common_APP/META/broker.xml' ...
BIP1140I: Overriding property FTP_To_Trg#FileOut with 'ftp.test.com' in 'App_Common_APP/META/broker.xml' ...
BIP1140I: Overriding property Email#UDP_SysNm with 'SIT' in 'App_Common_APP/META/broker.xml' ...
```

I have updated file paths and tried it didn't work, after running the script I don't see anything happening, providing file paths caused an issue?

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN (C:\Users\k2\file.txt) DO FOR %%y IN (%%e) DO (
 SET "word=%%y"
 IF "!word:~0,1!!word:~-1!"=="''" (
  FIND "!word:~1,-2!" C:\Users\k2\result.txt>nul
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (>>C:\Users\k2 ECHO %%y) ELSE (>>C:\Users\k2 ECHO %%y)
 )
)
```

Tried with file names and yet I don't see anything happening, I have also provided double quotes("") for filePaths, is that issue?

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN ("C:\Users\k2\file.txt") DO FOR %%y IN (%%e) DO (
 ECHO %%y
 SET "word=%%y"
 IF "!word:~0,1!!word:~-1!"=="''" (
 ECHO processing %%y
  FIND "!word:~1,-2!" "C:\Users\k2\result.txt">nul
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (>>"C:\Users\k2\Failure.txt" ECHO %%y) 
  ELSE (>>"C:\Users\k2\Success.txt" ECHO %%y)
 )
)
```

Comment: Stackoverflow.com <https://stackoverflow.com/> is not a free script/code writing service. Edit *relevant section(s)* of what you have tried into your question along with appropriate representative data (use cut/paste) & say what your actual & expected results are. We can try to help with specific problems. This problem can be solved in two lines of code, making presumptions eg does the "other text file" contain the quotes?
You should also read How do I ask a good question?
<https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask>. Requests for code to be written are off-topic & will be closed.

Comment: I have absolutely tried but mine is just checking the specific text from a file, I need to read 1 by 1 line and find the same value in another file.

```
FINDSTR /I "plp api.com" C:\Users\k2\file.txt >> "C:\Users\k2\result.txt"
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
 ECHO Error
) ELSE (
     ECHO "Build Complete"
)
PAUSE
```

Comment: Please don't post code into comments - use the `edit` button to edit it into your question. Highlight it and press `{}` to indented for display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to adapt this:

```
@ECHO Off&SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN (q77438851.txt) DO FOR %%y IN (%%e) DO SET "word=%%y"&IF "!word:~0,1!!word:~-1!"=="''" FIND "!word:~1,-2!" q77438851_2.txt>nul&IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (>>u:\miss ECHO %%y) ELSE (>>u:\hit ECHO %%y)
```

(which just proves it can be done in two lines) - reformatting to a better layout

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN (q77438851.txt) DO FOR %%y IN (%%e) DO (
 SET "word=%%y"
 IF "!word:~0,1!!word:~-1!"=="''" (
  FIND "!word:~1,-2!" q77438851_2.txt>nul
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (>>u:\miss ECHO %%y) ELSE (>>u:\hit ECHO %%y)
 )
)
```

`q77438851.txt` is my test file, `q77438851_2.txt` the other file in which to locate the found-strings.

Read each line from `q77438851.txt` to `%%e`, then assign `%%y` to each space-separated string in turn (note: also uses `,;` as separators)

Assign the "word" found to `word` as you cannot substring a `metavariable` (`%%e %%y`)

See whether the first character and the last character of `word` are both `'`. and if so...

Locate the substring of `word` from the second to the second-last character in the second file using `find`, directing `find`'s output to the bit-bin and setting `errorlevel` to `0` if found and non-`0` if not found.

Write the quoted word found (in `%%y`) to either the `hit` or `miss` file (My `U:` is a ramdrive)

Obviously, the destination files used would need to be cleared before the run is made - or they could be deleted within the script.

Substring handling - see `set /?` from the prompt for docco or thousands of examples on SO.

Edit in response to comment - first quoted string only

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%e IN ("q77438851.txt") DO SET "first=y"&FOR %%y IN (%%e) DO (
 SET "word=%%y"
 if defined first IF "!word:~0,1!!word:~-1!"=="''" (
  set "first="
  FIND "!word:~1,-2!" q77438851_2.txt>nul
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (>>u:\miss ECHO %%y) ELSE (>>u:\hit ECHO %%y)
 )
)
```

Set `first` to a value for each line read.

If `first` is defined AND it's aquoted word, set `first` to *nothing* (which means it becomes undefined - but will be re-defined when the next line is read)

Comment: I have updated file paths and tried it didn't work, after running the script I don't see anything happening, providing file paths caused an issue? Updated the question.

Comment: `>>C:\Users\k2` you have used twice on the `if errorlevel...` line. `C:\Users\k2` is a directory. You need to add a filename (...\hit.txt    ...\miss.txt). You could also add a line `echo %%y` before the `set "word=` line to display the individual words found, and if that makes sense, add `echo processing %%y` before the `FIND "...` line.

Comment: Tried with file names and yet I don't see anything happening, I have also provided double quotes("") for filePaths, is that an issue? updated the question.

Comment: Yes - if the filename in `FOR /f "delims=" %%e IN (q77438851.txt)` is quoted, you need `"usebackqdelims="` otherwise `for/f` will analyse the quoted name as a simple string. See `for /?` from the prompt for docco, or the usual thousands of examples on SO

Comment: In a line there can more than 1 value with single quotes (' '), I just need to pick the first 1 value.

Comment: `for /f "tokens=2 delims='` %%a in (file.txt) do echo %%a`

Comment: That didn't work for some reason, script failed to execute

Comment: @Stephan: do I need to add the after first for?

Comment: @Magoo: ```"usebackqdelims="```` worked as expected. In a line there can more than 1 value with single quotes (' '). Can we just pick the values from 1st occurrences of the single quotes (' ') in file.txt, we don't need 2nd set of single quotes (' ')